# Trying to use default modifier (requires java8+) in an annotated interface yields an error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am a beginner using spring, I am trying to use `default` modifier (requires java8+) in an annotated interface. but I am getting an error `default modifier is not aloud here` does anyone familiar with this issue ? is something todo with spring version or with spring in general ?
I am using `springBootVersion=2.1.16.RELEASE`

**Edit:**
I cannot remove the annotation because more annotations involved

```
@//other annotations
@Documented
public @interface Foo {
    public default String fooName() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

> java: modifier default not allowed here

Comment: default methods only apply to interfaces, not annotations.

Comment: In other words, remove the `@` and your code will compile. For more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

Comment: BTW, to clarify the point: it has nothing to do with Spring, its a pure java syntax, default methods on annotations are not supported hence you have a compilation error, that's it

Answer (score 1):

The default method is applicable only for the interface. This feature was introduced as part of Java 8 release.

Here you are trying to add default method to annotations, but the default method is not supported for annotation. Due to this, you are getting error.

Ideally, annotations are used in java to pass the meta-data for a particular class, method or files. So in a normal scenario, your annotation should not contain the concrete method with the body.

If you are trying to create an interface with a default method than remove the `@`.

```
public interface Foo {
    public default String fooName() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Or if you are trying to create an annotation then it should not be default method and remove default keyword and the method body.

```
public @interface Foo {
    public String fooName();
}
```